# rotate matlab colorbar tick labels

Tags: matlab, colorbar

I have the following which generates a colorbar.  However, the orientation of the tick labels means that if the font is increased they will run together.  Thus I need to rotate the tick lables in order to make them bigger *and* still legible

```
   figure;
   tiledlayout(1,1);
   skipticks = 3;
   t1=nexttile;
   [X,Y] = meshgrid(1:0.5:10,1:20);
   Z = sin(X) + cos(Y);
   offset = rand(1)*1e-6;
   Z = Z*1e-14 + offset;
   pcolor(X,Y,Z)
   cmorig = colormap(gca);
   view(2)
   colorbar('southoutside');
```

Result:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Comment: Why do you think that the 8th decimal place in your data is meaningful? I have never before seen a graph showing the differences in the 8th decimal place. Highly unusual. If this is actually meaningful, you could consider removing the offset, and writing that in the legend of the figure (or next to the "x10-7" annotation). That is, show relative differences in your graph.

Comment: I thought about doing this, but I've never seen a paper where someone did this

Comment: I think it would actually improve legibility. Your desired output graph is hard to decipher because it’s not clear at first why tick marks have so many digits, and then it takes a bit to figure out what the magnitude of the differences are, you basically need to count digits. Usually tick marks have values that are easy to read, you put tick marks at rounded values for that purpose.

Comment: There is no [official property in in `colorbar`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.illustration.colorbar-properties.html) to rotate the labels

Comment: I actually ended up using the suggested technique of removing the offset and am pleased with the result.  After offsetting, only 1 significant figure was required to explain most of the variation.